# SimpleXML fetch tag incl. all child-elements

Tags: php, xml, rss, tags, simplexml

I would like to parse an rss-file with simplexml. If I print a specific tag, direct content is selected only - no children and "sub"-tags are included. How can I access a tag incl. children-tag names and their content?

```
//load rss into $xml
foreach ($this->xml->channel->item as $item) {
  echo "<h3>{$this->out($item->title)}</h3>",
       $this->out($item->description);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $this->xml->children() to get child nodes, and then use that recursively. I recently wrote a method to copy one XML block recursively into another - which should show you the techniques you can use.

```
protected function copyXml(SimpleXMLElement $from, SimpleXMLElement $to)
{
    // Create a new branch in the target, as per the source
    $fromValue = (string) $from;
    if ($fromValue)
    {
        $toChild = $to->addChild($from->getName(), (string) $from);
    }
    else
    {
        $toChild = $to->addChild($from->getName());
    }

    // Copy attributes across
    foreach ($from->attributes() as $name => $value)
    {
        $toChild->addAttribute($name, $value);
    }

    // Copy any children across, recursively
    foreach ($from->children() as $fromChild)
    {
        $this->copyXml($fromChild, $toChild);
    }
}
```

HTH.